# Python indexing of array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

So I just red here on Stackoverflow that you can select every Nth row and column of an array by doing:

```
image[0::N, 0::N]
```

which made me wonder since "normal" indexing is done by:

```
image[x][y]
```

Please explain why in the first example it is done via a comma between the indexes and in the second example by two separate brackets?

The array image is created via:

```
image = skipy.misc.imread('image.png', flatten=True)
```

I'd also appreciate a link to a page where I can inform myself further on this

Comment: Did you read the [NumPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)?

Comment: That's great thank you! I haven't had a key-word which I could google to find the proper information but slice notation it is!

Comment: The comma doesn't work on a Python list. That syntax is used on Numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma separator in Numpy arrays - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Separate brackets would work for Numpy arrays as well

Comment: Please make sure to post a very small summary of the resource you linked to.